# Adding alignment marker & gives: Error: Extra }, or forgotten \right \end{align}

Tags: errors, equations, align

I have a weird problem with the Align environment in combination with brackets spanning more than 1 line. When I add alignment markers (&) to my equation in the Align environment I suddenly get an error saying that I have an extra }.

The minimal example that reproduces the error looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
    J      =& 2  \left[3x \right.  \nonumber  \\
    \left. +& 4  \right]
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

If i take out the & it works. If I take out the brackets it also works. Can anyone explain what is going on and how I can overcome this issue?

For completeness, the actual equation looks like this:

```
\begin{align}
 J=E-\Delta P V =& \gamma\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_0^{r_0}\left[\sqrt{r^2+r^2 \partial_r z^2 + \partial_\phi z^2}-r \cos\theta_Y \right. \nonumber  \\
\left. + & \,\frac{\rho g}{\gamma} z r \left(\frac{z}{2}\cos\alpha-r \sin \alpha \cos\phi\right)-\Delta P r z  \right] dr d\phi
\end{align}
```

Comment: You can't start `\left` in an alignment cell and have `\right` in another one. In the example there's no need of `\left` and `\right`, by the way.

Comment: @egreg I know that there is no need for the \left \right here, but this is a minimal example to reproduce the issue. The actual equation contains several larger terms

Comment: I remarked it because it's frequent to see `\left` and `\right` where they serve no purpose. Can you add a sample of the real thing?

Comment: The actual equation looks like shown in the edit

Comment: @Michiel Please observe the correct position of the pair `&` and `=`.

Comment: I'd use `multline` rather than `align`. In place of `\left[` use `\biggl[`; similarly, use `\biggr]` instead of `\right]` and remove the empty delimiters (and of course `&`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
    J &= 2 \left[3x \right. \nonumber \\
     &+ \left. 4  \right]
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem in your MWE was that you put a `&` between your left and right delimiter. Instead of the automatic solution of `\left[` and `\right]` I would recommend a manual choice for most cases (especially here, where the bracket from first line could get another automatic sizing than the bracket from the second line). In the following MWE, you can see how to use `\bigl[`/`\bigr]` as an example. In this very case, you could just use `[ ]`, as you do not need enlarged brackets.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
    J &= 2 \bigl[3x \nonumber \\
     &\quad+ 4\bigr]
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

And here is your real example:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\der}{\,\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
J&=E-\Delta PV\nonumber\\
&=\gamma\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_0^{r_0}\biggl[\sqrt{r^2+r^2 \partial_r z^2 + \partial_\phi z^2}-r \cos\theta_Y \nonumber  \\
&\phantom{{}=\gamma\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_0^{r_0}\biggl[}+\frac{\rho g}{\gamma} zr \biggl(\frac{z}{2}\cos\alpha-r \sin \alpha \cos\phi\biggr)-\Delta Prz\biggr] \der r\der\phi
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is indeed what I was looking for. Didn't know that the `&` inside delimiters was an issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For a split equation like that, I would use `multline` rather than `align`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
J = E-\Delta P V =
\gamma\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_0^{r_0}\biggl[
  \sqrt{r^2+r^2 \partial_r z^2 + \partial_\phi z^2} - r \cos\theta_Y +{}\\
  \frac{\rho g}{\gamma} z r 
    \left(\frac{z}{2}\cos\alpha- r \sin \alpha \cos\phi\right) -
    \Delta P r z  
\biggr]\,dr \,d\phi
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the explicit sizing commands `\biggl` and `\biggr` that are unavoidable if the delimiters are in different parts of a display (including different cells in a single row of `align`).

If you prefer a three stage display, use `split`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
J &= E-\Delta P V\\
&= \gamma\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_0^{r_0}\biggl[
     \sqrt{r^2+r^2 \partial_r z^2 + \partial_\phi z^2} - r \cos\theta_Y +{}\\
&\hspace{6em}\frac{\rho g}{\gamma} z r
     \left(\frac{z}{2}\cos\alpha- r \sin \alpha \cos\phi\right) -
     \Delta P r z
\biggr]\,dr \,d\phi
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The `\hspace{6em}` bit has been computed by eye; with a `\hphantom` you can add the precise space for aligning to something in the line above, although it doesn't seem necessary.

[image]

Comment: This also looks nice, but I prefer to have control over the alignment

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
    J      &= 2  \left[3x \right.  \nonumber  \\
     & \left.{}+ 4  \right]
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

1. In your example the pair `\left` `\right` was separated by `&`, not being a group.
2. Please observe the switch  of `&` and `=`.
3. Using the group `left` and `right` is easy, but not recommended. In particular the effective sizes of parentheses may be different in different lines.
4. I would rather add, e.g., `\quad` before `+` in the second line.

Comment: Bad idea, may end up with different sizes depending on the material. Manual scaling is better.

Comment: @daleif Certainly, but the other mistakes were more important for me.

Comment: My point is just that others will read this when searching the archives and ought to be told that it is not a good solution in general.

Comment: @daleif I have just added, with an additional remark.